# 2.8 Basic Unwrap Problem?

Tags: uv

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0trhFMBdVzI&feature=youtu.be 
Video of the problem

Right, so I have a problem. I just downloaded 2.8beta and I can't unwrap anything it seems. Unless I am completely misunderstanding a new workflow.

Seems when I try to unwrap something, it doesn't appear inside the UV editor.
And whenever I try to open a side panel or do anything there I get a message that reads

*Tool 'Select Box' not found for space 'IMAGE_EDITOR'.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 2.8 where is new **View** mode in **uv/image editor**.
In this mode where is no UVs or mask or painting tools are display. To edit UV you need to switch to **UV edit** mode:

[image]

New View mode is good for viewing image for reference.

Note, that where is new *UV editing* workspace with uv/image editor with uv edit mode by default:

[image]

*`Tool 'Select Box' not found for space 'IMAGE_EDITOR'`* it is just a warning don't pay attention to it.

Answer (score 4):

[The UV Editor is now its own editor in the editors menu, not a mode of the image editor.](https://developer.blender.org/T59289)